# In C++, what does it mean when equals is used twice?

Tags: c++

My apologies if this is a duplicate: searching for this isn't easy.

Example code taken from [rtorrent](https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent/blob/master/src/ui/element_download_list.cc#L100):

```
m_bindings[KEY_UP] = m_bindings['P' - '@'] = std::bind(&ElementDownloadList::receive_prev, this);
```

What does the double value-setting mean, and how can this statement be explained?

Comment: The assignment operator evaluates to the assigned value, if that helps.

Comment: `std::bind` creates some kind of callable object, which then maybe gets assigned, depending on what the the type of m_bindings is  - what the rest is doing is hard to say.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression is evaluated from the right equals sign to the left. The statement `a = b = c` can be rewritten `a = (b = c)`. The result of an `=` operation is the value that was assigned. Thus the result of `(b = c)` is `c`, making the next operation equivalent to `a = c`.

Answer (score 2):

This is called operator chaining.  What you are doing is assigning the return value of the right hand `operator =` to the left hand `operator =`

It is equivalent to doing

```
m_bindings['P' - '@'] = std::bind(&ElementDownloadList::receive_prev, this);
m_bindings[KEY_UP] = m_bindings['P' - '@'];
```

but saves you a line of code.  It also saves you from calling `operator[]` a second time, which could be expensive.  Personally, I would use the 2 line version to make the code easier to read unless performance is really an issue.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to `x = y = 1` which is short hand for `y = 1` and `x = y`.